# position ImageItem on top right corner of screen

Tags: java, image, swing, java-me

I am having issues with adding an Image to a screen, I have the following code:

```
  try {
    Image cima = Image.createImage("/resources/cross.png");
  } catch (IOException ex){
    System.out.println("ERROR");
  }
```

However it always hits up the exception. I don't know what's wrong as I already put in the image in the correct folder

[image]

Also would it be possible to combine two layout settings? Say I want top right corner? I want to combine two layout..is this possible?

**UPDATE:**

With regards to the layout I want to do something like:

```
form.append(new ImageItem("Top Right", cima, ImageItem.LAYOUT_TOP, null));
```

but this only gives me the image on TOP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the URL is wrong. See my answer to this related question:

- [Reading an image in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014123/reading-an-image-in-netbeans/7014177#7014177)

As for your second question, it is possible to combine multiple layout managers, although each container is limited to *exactly one*. For more information, see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

<strike>And what exactly do you want to set in the top right corner? I'm sure this can be done using a single layout manager.</strike>

As for placing the image in the top-right corner of the container, there are *many ways* to achieve this. One way is to simply use a `JLabel` as seen in the answer provided by [@camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850949/how-to-place-jlabel-on-top-right-corner-just-below-the-title-bar) question.

Comment: I tried Image cima = Image.createImage("../res/cross.png"); and it didn't work as well

Comment: @adit, Are you talking about [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) Image class? If so, there is no `createImage` method. Also, you clearly didn't thoroughly read my example since that's not what I told you to do.

Comment: I am talking about http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html

Comment: @adit, Oh well it's still a _path_ problem. Look at my sample code again.

Comment: I saw you have a resources folder, I don't know how to create that in Eclipse

Comment: now I did create a resource folder, tried everything starting from ../HW1.resources/cross.png and resources/cross.png, etc.. Nothing works

Comment: @adit, Sorry, I've been busy. I see that you've accepted my answer. Did you finally get it working?

Answer (score 1):

The package isn't named "res", but "resources" as we can see from your snapshot.

```
Image cima = ImageIO.read(YourClass.class.getResource("/resources/cross.png"));
```

---

Change the catch body to this:

```
} catch (IOException ex){
  System.out.println("ERROR");
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

And tell us what exception you've got.